# Host ID on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS 32-bit

Tags: 12.04, networking

I would like to learn the host ID of my system, how can I do so? In accordance with the following page http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3651.html, I checked it by invoking the command

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0
```

However, it returned that the device was not found. When I invoked the same command without eth0 this time I got the MAC address of eth1, but according to the site aforementioned this is not a valid host ID. Can someone provide assistance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To find host ID run `hostid` in Terminal.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/hostid.1.html

Comment: Thanks, but my concern is the host ID used by some programs such as Maple for binding the license to a particular software and hardware configuration.

Comment: Yes this displays an host ID as a 8-digit number. Thanks for your help.